# Isolate IoJs from Nodejs

Tags: node.js, io.js

I've just installed [io.js](https://iojs.org/) and I noticed that now `node` command is actually running iojs (on mac os), instead of my previous installation of node.js

Is there a way of using node.js and io.js on the same machine?

Comment: https://github.com/iojs/io.js/issues/43 - manual installation for now.

Answer (score 2):

One good options is to use Node Version Manager (NVM).

https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Latest version 0.23.0 supports seamless switching between node and io.js